# Styling span into multiple lines

Tags: html, css, styles

this is my html:

```
<div class="Item-Text>
     does not contain: <span class="Item-Props">fdsf sdfds f</span>
     , <span class="Item-Props">is</span>
     , <span class="Item-Props">is not</span>
     , <span class="Item-Props">contains</span>
     , <span class="Item-Props">does not contain</span>
     , <span class="Item-Props">Entry</span> 
</div>
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mato75/Labor4az/3/

but I would like it that it would have some max width and it will be presented in multiple lines.

Comment: actually people use `ul` for this!

Comment: `span{display:block;}` <- **CSS**

Comment: Where should the commas appear?

Comment: updated the example with how I would like it to look

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Labor4az/4/)

```
.Item-Text { max-width:150px; }
```

Comment: I am sorry, this is not ok, because a new line should start when the text gets to the max width, I will update the example, with what i would like to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your class with Item-Props

```
.Item-Props {
    color: red;display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<ul>` for this

```
<div class="Item-Text">does not contain:
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li class="Item-Props">fdsf sdfds f,</li>
        <li class="Item-Props">is,</li>
        <li class="Item-Props">is not,</li>
        <li class="Item-Props">contains,</li>
        <li class="Item-Props">does not contain,</li>
        <li class="Item-Props">Entry,</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```